# Retain only unique/distinct columns for each row of an input table

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a very large data frame (nrow=~273,000) which I've subset as an example below: Each row is a protein name(s) and has various numbers of columns that lists the subcellular structures in which they can be found in human cells. 1) I would like to remove duplicate entries for each row and am struggling with this (code below). 2) I would then like to be able to count how many columns (subcellular structures) each gene can be found in.

Background: I got this data from Uniprot and cleaned it up as best as I could using regex but there are still some cases where there are rows with duplicate entries (e.g. FMR1 lists Chromosome 2x, Cytoplasm 3x and Plasma Membrane 2x - furthermore there are some blank columns in between them)

```
dput(df1)
structure(list(FMR1 = structure(c(41L, 3L, 17L, 63L, 16L, 24L, 
35L, 33L, 52L, 6L, 49L, 5L, 71L, 72L, 42L, 58L, 22L, 20L, 19L, 
80L, 9L, 51L, 66L, 64L, 23L, 14L, 60L, 45L, 28L, 54L, 7L, 30L, 
29L, 44L, 53L, 8L, 69L, 79L, 10L, 11L, 26L, 37L, 39L, 40L, 82L, 
73L, 18L, 21L, 27L, 47L, 4L, 46L, 1L, 13L, 36L, 70L, 74L, 67L, 
78L, 77L, 61L, 62L, 31L, 56L, 34L, 57L, 25L, 81L, 75L, 59L, 2L, 
65L, 55L, 38L, 50L, 68L, 32L, 12L, 43L, 15L, 48L, 76L), .Label = c("AAMP", 
"ADCY10 SAC", "AIMP1 EMAP2 SCYE1", "ANTXR2 CMG2", "APBB1 FE65 RIR", 
"APC DP2", "APLP1", "ARHGAP26 GRAF KIAA0621 OPHN1L", "ARL4A ARL4", 
"ATP6V0D1 ATP6D VPATPD", "ATP6V1D ATP6M VATD", "AZIN2 ADC KIAA1945 ODCP", 
"CACNB2 CACNLB2 MYSB", "CAMK2D CAMKD", "CDCA8 PESCRG3", "CDK1 CDC2 CDC28A CDKN1 P34CDC2", 
"CEMIP KIAA1199", "CIB1 CIB KIP PRKDCIP", "CLTA", "CLTB", "CMTM8 CKLFSF8", 
"DMD", "DSP", "ECT2", "EHD2 PAST2", "ENTPD2 CD39L1", "ERBB2 HER2 MLN19 NEU NGL", 
"EVPL", "FCHO1 KIAA0290", "FCHO2", "FGR SRC2", "GPER1 CEPR CMKRL2 DRY12 GPER GPR30", 
"HDAC6 KIAA0901 JM21", "ITCH", "ITGB1BP1 ICAP1", "KCTD7", "KIFC3", 
"MFN1", "MISP C19orf21", "MYOT TTID", "NGDN C14orf120", "NISCH IRAS KIAA0975", 
"NR1D1 EAR1 HREV THRAL", "PGM5 PGMRP", "PKP4", "PLA2G6 PLPLA9", 
"PNKD KIAA1184 MR1 TAHCCP2 FKSG19 UNQ2491/PRO5778", "POP7 RPP20", 
"PPL KIAA0568", "PRDX3 AOP1", "PTOV1 ACID2 PP642 UNQ6127/PRO20092", 
"PTPN23 KIAA1471", "PTPRE", "PTPRR ECPTP PTPRQ", "RAB13 GIG4", 
"RAB23 HSPC137", "RAB29 RAB7L1", "RAB30", "RAB38", "RAB40AL RLGP", 
"RAB8A MEL RAB8", "RAB9A RAB9", "RACGAP1 KIAA1478 MGCRACGAP", 
"RAP1B OK/SW-cl", "RGS8", "RPSA LAMBR LAMR1", "SGIP1", "SHMT2", 
"SHROOM3 KIAA1481 SHRML MSTP013", "SLC28A3 CNT3", "SNTA1 SNT1", 
"SNTB1 SNT2B1", "SNX11", "SNX12", "STOM BND7 EPB72", "TEX10 L18 Nbla10363", 
"TNFRSF8 CD30 D1S166E", "TNS4 CTEN PP14434", "TRIM72 MG53", "USP6 HRP1 TRE2", 
"VCL", "YES1 YES"), class = "factor"), Nucleus = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("Mitochondrion  ", "Nucleus", "Nucleus  ", "Plasma membrane", 
"Plasma membrane  "), class = "factor"), Chromosome = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("Chromosome", "Cytoplasm", "Cytoplasm  "), class = "factor"), 
    Chromosome.1 = structure(c(4L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 14L, 12L, 20L, 
    18L, 5L, 20L, 20L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 10L, 19L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 
    16L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 15L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L, 22L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 
    7L, 14L, 9L, 17L, 11L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 17L, 18L, 10L, 1L, 
    1L, 17L, 19L, 19L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("", " ", "Chromosome", 
    "Cytoplasm  ", "Cytoplasmic vesicle", "Cytoplasmic vesicle  ", 
    "Endoplasmic reticulum", "Endosome", "Endosome  ", "Golgi apparatus", 
    "Golgi apparatus  ", "Midbody", "Midbody  ", "Mitochondrion", 
    "Mitochondrion  ", "Nucleus", "Nucleus  ", "Perikaryon  ", 
    "Plasma membrane", "Plasma membrane  ", "Sarcoplasmic reticulum  ", 
    "Secreted"), class = "factor"), Cytoplasm = structure(c(1L, 
    15L, 13L, 10L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    5L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 11L, 12L, 
    5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", " ", 
    "Cytoplasmic vesicle", "Endoplasmic reticulum", "Endosome", 
    "Endosome  ", "Golgi apparatus", "Golgi apparatus  ", "Golgi appartus", 
    "Midbody", "Mitochondrion  ", "Nucleus  ", "Plasma membrane", 
    "Plasma membrane  ", "Secreted  "), class = "factor"), Cytoplasm.1 = structure(c(1L, 
    4L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    6L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", " ", "Endoplasmic reticulum", 
    "Endoplasmic reticulum  ", "Endosome", "Mitochondrion", "Plasma membrane"
    ), class = "factor"), Cytoplasmic.vesicle = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Golgi apparatus"
    ), class = "factor"), Perikaryon = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", " ", "Golgi apparatus"), class = "factor"), 
    X = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "Cytoplasmic granule"), class = "factor"), X.1 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Perikaryon"), class = "factor"), 
    X.2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X.3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Plasma.membrane = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), Plasma.membrane.1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    )), .Names = c("FMR1", "Nucleus", "Chromosome", "Chromosome.1", 
"Cytoplasm", "Cytoplasm.1", "Cytoplasmic.vesicle", "Perikaryon", 
"X", "X.1", "X.2", "X.3", "Plasma.membrane", "Plasma.membrane.1"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -82L))
```

I've tried getting only unique columns for each row with no luck, for example:

```
unique(df1) # Original data with repeats removed
dplyr::distinct(df1) # Retain only unique/distinct rows from an input tb
```

I think the problem is that the above functions are looking for row names which are identical which is not what I want. I want distinct columns for each row. I was thinking of using the `melt` function but since there is an odd number of columns for each row this won't work.

I would expect the output to look like this `newDF`

```
structure(list(FMR1 = structure(c(7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 
5L, 8L), .Label = c("AIMP1 EMAP2 SCYE1", "CDK1 CDC2 CDC28A CDKN1 P34CDC2", 
"CEMIP KIAA1199", "ECT2", "HDAC6 KIAA0901 JM21", "ITGB1BP1 ICAP1", 
"NGDN C14orf120", "PTPN23 KIAA1471", "RACGAP1 KIAA1478 MGCRACGAP"
), class = "factor"), Nucleus = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Nucleus", "Nucleus  "), class = "factor"), 
    Chromosome = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("Chromosome", "Cytoplasm"), class = "factor"), 
    Cytoplasmic.vesicle = structure(c(1L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
    7L, 6L, 3L), .Label = c("Cytoplasm  ", "Endoplasmic reticulum", 
    "Endosome", "Midbody", "Mitochondrion", "Perikaryon  ", "Plasma membrane  ", 
    "Secreted  "), class = "factor"), Perikaryon = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Endoplasmic reticulum  ", 
    "Plasma membrane"), class = "factor"), Plasma.membrane = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("FMR1", "Nucleus", 
"Chromosome", "Cytoplasmic.vesicle", "Perikaryon", "Plasma.membrane"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

From here I would like to get a `rowSums(df1)` so I was thinking of coercing each term to a number (e.g. Cytoplasmic vesicle=1, Nucleus=1, Endoplasmic reticiulum=1, etc.) but run into a problem on this dummy-dataset.

```
df2 <- as.numeric(newDF)
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
df2 <- as.numeric(newDF[,2:n])
Error in 2:n : NA/NaN argument
```

Thank you for your help.

EDIT

I would like to get a count for each row of how many unique columns in the `newDF` like so:

```
FMR1 5
NGDN C14orf120 3
AIMP1 EMAP2 SCYE1 4
CEMIP KIAA1199 4
RACGAP1 KIAA1478 MGCRACGAP 4
CDK1 CDC2 CDC28A CDKN1 P34CDC2 3
ECT2 4
ITGB1BP1 ICAP1 3
HDAC6 KIAA0901 JM21 3
PTPN23 KIAA1471 3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Improve efficiency for removing duplicate values per row and shift values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47493557/improve-efficiency-for-removing-duplicate-values-per-row-and-shift-values-in-r)

Comment: @Hardikgupta The suggested answers in that link do not work for my data. For example:

`privefl = as.data.frame(t(apply(t(temp), 2, myf)))`

For protein FMR1 it only partially shifted values over, there is still one empty column in-between **Perikaryon** and **Plasma membrane**, with no NA value. It has not removed any of the duplicate values either.

Comment: @MatthewJ.Oldach I would like to know your expected outcome. Reading your question, you want to how many columns each gene appeared. So You want to see a data frame with the names of genes and total numbers. Is that right?

Comment: I edited the post for my expected outcome. I'm not looking for how many columns each gene appeared. I'm interested in how many unique columns there is for each row (i.e. gene).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be one way to go. Since your expected result is a character vector, I cannot visualize the final output. Yet, you said you want to check how many columns each protein appears in in the data. I hope the outcome I have is what you are after.

First, I converted all columns to character. Then, I converted the data to long format one using `gather()`. For each subcellular structure group (i.e., subcellular), I added row indices (e.g., 1 means the 1st row in your original data), and trim white space. Then, remove any rows with `NA` in protein. Remove any rows with `""` and `" "`. Now tidying up is done. For each row (i.e., `row.index`), remove duplicated protein types.
Ungroup the data, and finally count how many columns each protein appears (i.e., sucellular structure). Basically, you want to count how many times each protein appear in the data set by this time.

With your sample data, I got the following result. But I am not sure if this is what you want. (I am off to bed now. So I cannot help you for some hours. If anybody can jump in, please do so.)

```
mutate_all(mydf, as.character) %>%
gather(key = subcellular, value = protein) %>%
group_by(subcellular) %>%
mutate(row.index = 1:n(), 
       protein = trimws(protein)) %>%
filter(!is.na(protein)) %>%
filter(!protein %in% c("", " ")) %>%
group_by(row.index) %>%
filter(!duplicated(protein)) %>%
ungroup %>%
count(protein, sort = TRUE)


#                  protein     n
#                   <chr> <int>
# 1             Cytoplasm    82
# 2       Plasma membrane    70
# 3               Nucleus    25
# 4              Endosome     9
# 5         Mitochondrion     9
# 6   Cytoplasmic vesicle     8
# 7       Golgi apparatus     7
# 8 Endoplasmic reticulum     5
# 9               Midbody     3
#10            Perikaryon     3
# ... with 87 more rows
```

Given jjl"s comment, I did the following. Instead of counting how many columns each protein appears in, I counted how many protein names exist for each row.

```
mutate_all(mydf, as.character) %>%
gather(key = subcellular, value = protein) %>%
group_by(subcellular) %>%
mutate(row.index = 1:n(), 
       protein = trimws(protein)) %>%
filter(!is.na(protein)) %>%
filter(!protein %in% c("", " ")) %>%
group_by(row.index) %>%
filter(!duplicated(protein)) %>%
ungroup %>%
count(row.index)

#   row.index     n
#       <int> <int>
# 1         1     4
# 2         2     6
# 3         3     5
# 4         4     6
# 5         5     4
# 6         6     5
# 7         7     4
# 8         8     4
# 9         9     5
#10        10     3
# ... with 72 more rows
```

## EDIT

If you want to remove the 1st column (i.e, `FMR1`), you can do that by filtering that column. I added `filter(subcellular != "FMR1")` to my code before I used `count()` at the end.

```
mutate_all(mydf, as.character) %>%
gather(key = subcellular, value = protein) %>%
group_by(subcellular) %>%
mutate(row.index = 1:n(), 
       protein = trimws(protein)) %>%
filter(!is.na(protein)) %>%
filter(!protein %in% c("", " ")) %>%
group_by(row.index) %>%
filter(!duplicated(protein)) %>%
ungroup %>%
filter(subcellular != "FMR1") %>%
count(row.index)

# A tibble: 9 x 2
#  row.index     n
#      <int> <int>
#1         1     3
#2         2     4
#3         3     4
#4         4     4
#5         5     3
#6         6     4
#7         7     3
#8         8     3
#9         9     3
```

Comment: Nice answer. If I interpret the `rowSums(df1)` call correctly, he wants to know how many compartments there are per protein rather than the frequency of the compartments. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Thank you @jjl that is correct, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much @jazzurro for the edit "how many names exist for each row". I've only worked a bit before with tidyr and dplyr but you've really inspired me to learn more about the dplyr package. I've just bought a membership to datacamp.com and will be taking the [Joining Data in R with dplyr](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/joining-data-in-r-with-dplyr) class :)

Comment: @MatthewJ.Oldach I am glad to hear that. So I guess my second suggestion was the one you were looking for. Is that correct? If your case is done, will you close it by ticking a green tick next to the up/down vote triangles? Then, SO users know that your case is closed. Learning dplyr is a fun thing. Enjoy! :)

Comment: One thing I should point out for anyone going through this post in the future is that @jazzurro solution counts every column, including the protein (first column), so I just have to subtract one from everything; no big problem. My work around was `df$n <- (df$n - 1)`

I tried to switch `row.index = 2:n()` but this tosses up and error so I'm not sure how to edit their solution.

Comment: @MatthewJ.Oldach So you want to remove the first column, right? Let me add that info for you.

Comment: Haha you're very quick to respond I was about to close the case by upvoting your solution. I just was typing this last comment and was trying to edit your solution a bit. Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewJ.Oldach I happen to be online now and got time. I am happy to do that for you.

Comment: @MatthewJ.Oldach I revised my answer. I hope this will suit your needs.